# Ubuntu 12.10 upgrade to 13.04 hang

Tags: upgrade, 13.04

I am on my macbook, I am upgrading from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04. The upgrade went fine, Up until about half way, Where it just stopped. No error message, And it is no frozen. Nothing is happening, It just says installed cabextract.

Answer (score 0):

If you managed to download all the files, and that it hanged under the installation, there is still a solution to re-take it.

When that happened to me earlier, I tried to run `sudo apt-get -f install`, and it just started where it had stopped. **Please correct me if i am wrong readers!**

And, the software updater will automatically detect if there is aproblem in the database, and it will ask you to run a "partial" upgrade.

Good Luck!